# OpenTSA and PKCS11

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, openssl, timestamp, pkcs11

We are planning to implement the time-stamping service ([RFC 3161](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3161)) using OpenTSA and we wanted to know:

### Does OpenTSA support PKCS #11 (Cryptoki) to talk to HSMs?

BTW: I did not find documentation or much information on OpenTSA.

It would be really helpful if you could comment on the support of PCKS #11 by OpenTSA.

Comment: Does OpenTSA even exist anymore? (Last [archive.org-snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20090413105743/http://www.opentsa.org/site/))

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're asking how to generate a timestamp response as defined in timestamp-protocol: [RFC3161](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt), with `openssl` to generate and sign the response using a `PKCS#11` (HSM in your case) as a TSA signer.

I think that there is no native way to use `PKCS#11`with `openssl` to do this. (maybe with some plugin like: [opensc pkcs11 engine for openssl](https://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/engine_pkcs11)).

If you take a look on `ts` command documentation: https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ts.html. To generate a timestamp response you can use the follow command:

`openssl ts -reply [-config configfile] [-section tsa_section] [-queryfile request.tsq] [-passin password_src] [-signer tsa_cert.pem] [-inkey private.pem] [-chain certs_file.pem] [-policy object_id] [-in response.tsr] [-token_in] [-out response.tsr] [-token_out] [-text] [-engine id]`

The TSA signer certificate and private key are specified in the following parameters which specify that both must be in PEM format, so seems that use of `PKCS#11` it's not possible.

> -signer tsa_cert.pem
>   The signer certificate of the TSA in PEM format. The TSA signing certificate must have exactly one extended key usage assigned to it: timeStamping. The extended key usage must also be critical, otherwise the certificate is going to be refused. Overrides the signer_cert variable of the config file. (Optional)
>
> -inkey private.pem
>   The signer private key of the TSA in PEM format. Overrides the signer_key config file option. (Optional)

However as I comment before, it can be possible maybe using `opensc pkcs11 engine` for openssl, I can't confirm if it works because I'm unfamiliar with it engine. Take a look on this [quickstart guide](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Engine-pkcs11-quickstart) which may put you on the right direction.

Hope this helps,